# Trying to return json data from vimeo api in meteor

Tags: javascript, json, rest, meteor, vimeo

I am attempting to return some json data from the vimeo API in meteor and having some trouble with callbacks and server vs client stuff this is my following code, but it is not working because it can see the http request that's in a variable on the server side in client but if I put it in the client I get a blocking error

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var auth_url='http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/92861889.json';
}

 //invoke the server method
 if (Meteor.isClient) {
   result = Meteor.http.call("GET", auth_url);
    var issue = JSON.parse(result.content);
    console.log(issue);
 }
```

**Update: Current Error**

```
     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < test.js?6011fceba7e0032b9fbc7fe1cec33965967603ed:24
(anonymous function) test.js?6011fceba7e0032b9fbc7fe1cec33965967603ed:24
(anonymous function) httpcall_client.js:63
(anonymous function) underscore.js:750
xhr.onreadystatechange
```

**New Code**

Ok so I retyped all the code, The issue was a invisible character from copying and pasting, from what I could tell. However Than I got a cross origin error, so I did some more research and found this is the proper way to do the callback. However I am getting a error "cannot read property "content" of undefined" Some More help would be greatly appreciated. I chose a different url for the json just for testing purposes.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

    Meteor.methods({
      'remoteGet' : function(url, options){
        return HTTP.get(url,options);
      }
    });

  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.call('remoteGet', 'http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/ahd8tq6q?apikey=6c55fc2ded8114a1c08b8a914851de84',{

  },function(error,response){

    var issue = JSON.parse(response.content);
    console.log(issue);
});

}
```

Comment: Can you say a little more about how you want this to be called? I'm unclear if you want the server to call `HTTP.get` or the client... or is the client requesting that the server make the call and then return the parsed results?

Comment: @davidweldod Well to be honest I am not sure which is the best, my main goal is to parse to json data and output it in a template, I just wanted to first test to see if I could even see the data in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client async operations cannot be written in a sync style. Callback is required:

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {
   result = Meteor.http.call("GET", auth_url, function (err, result) {
     var issue = JSON.parse(result.content);
     console.log(issue);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Ok that fixed the blocking Error, However now I am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < test.js?6011fceba7e0032b9fbc7fe1cec33965967603ed:24
(anonymous function) test.js?6011fceba7e0032b9fbc7fe1cec33965967603ed:24
(anonymous function) httpcall_client.js:63
(anonymous function) underscore.js:750
xhr.onreadystatechange" Error I tried result.data instead gives me a console.log of null

Comment: I added some new code above, that im trying could you possibly give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Vimeo updated this Json data feed so it has to be :

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/{VIMEOID}
```